# Why is there no onmessage Event for ClientWebSocket Class in C# .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, websocket

I'm currently working with websockets and are forced to use the default library and some basic events like onmessage would be usefull to handle messages from the server.

**I was wondering why the ClientWebSocket Class in .NET 4.5 has no onmessage Events like the Client in the [websocket-sharp library](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp#websocket-client) ?**

Comment: since websocket-sharp is a custom libary...the base class is from microsoft...I enough is said ;D

Comment: where do you read that websocket-sharp is based on microsofts library ?

Comment: It is implementing the IDisposable-Interface?

Comment: btw: THAT syntax in my first comment...yeaa! __/sarcasm:off__

Comment: Yes it implements the IDisposable-Interface that makes it Disposable thats it, that doesn't have anything to do with my question